# Quality of image deteriorates when used fitinview and Qt:KeepAspectRatio

Tags: qt, qt4

I am using Qt and I want to display a image and I am displaying it in QGraphicsView and as the image is bigger than the dimensions of box of the QGraphicsView I used

```
ui->graphicsView->fitInView(viewraw->itemsBoundingRect() ,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

where viewraw contains pixmap address to my image, my problem of oversized image was solved with this but my new problem now is the image after automatic resizing by Qt now shows with very very bad quality, it is very very blurry

What should I do?

Is there any way to display the image fit in the box and no quality loss?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try enabling antialiasing:

```
ui->graphicsView->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing 
        | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform 
        | QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
```

---

You can use [`QLayout::setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#SizeConstraint-enum) on the layout containing the view, to resize the parent widget to fit the view. The size will be the one returned by the view `sceneRect()` function.

For example, the following code will resize the `QMainWindow` (and lock the size) so that both items are visible:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow mainWindow;
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(&mainWindow);
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(view);
    view->setScene(scene);

    mainWindow.layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(view);
    mainWindow.show();

    scene->addRect(-100,-100,10,10, QPen(), Qt::red );
    scene->addRect(600,450,10,10, QPen(), Qt::blue );

    return a.exec();
}
```

Or, since you are using the designer,

- in the widget tree, go to the parent item of the graphics view, it should have a layout,

  - if not (if the icon is this one: [image: No Layout Icon]), add one by left clicking on the item name and choose a layout in the "Lay Out" menu (if you only have one widget, the type of layout doesn't matter, just choose one),
- then go to the last option in the property panel for the same item, which should be "layoutSizeConstraint" and select the option "SetFixedSize".

Comment: No effect :(
The quality is as bad it was :(
Ok do you know how to expand the graphicsView box according to the picture size and consequently adjust the main window or something similar sort of? I just want 1. No quality loss 2. No scroll bars and should fit in window. I don't mind increasing the graphicsView window though.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand that I am newbie to Qt. Can you give me example code pls to understand more better?

Comment: @VarunChitre I added the example you requested.